# Does the penetrating magnetic field lines affect the Eddy currents cancellation of an exterior magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

[image]
If a Type-II superconductor's surface is placed near a resistive wire, and current($I$) is applied, during a short duration of time while the current is reaching steady state, the magnetic field of the current carrying wire is changing, and a consequence of that change is the induction of Eddy currents generated on the surface of the superconductor.

It's assumed that the magnetic fields cancel out, but would the field lines that's penetrating the superconductor effect the Eddy currents & cancellation?